# JMeter: How do I connect a raw socket then send + receive a byte array?

Tags: azure, jmeter, load-testing

I have a custom protocol based on TCP and need to load test it using a JMeter script in the Azure load testing tool.

```
1. Connect
Loop 
{
  2. Send 'Hello' + #0
  3. Listen for response
  4. Pause for 1 second
}
5. Loop to step 2, 30 times
```

How is can I do a raw connect to a socket and send a byte array?

Answer (score 0):

- 1  2 and 3 - [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) or [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it) sampler
- 4  - [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)
- 5  - "Loop Count" in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

  [image]

Comment: Hi, that's almost what I need, but the TCP Sampler disconnects and reconnects for each loop when I want it to remain connected. I tried ticking "Re-use connection" but it doesn't do what I need. I need the connect outside the loop, then (send data + sleep 1s) in a loop using that same connection.

Comment: Have you considered a Windows sockets virtual user or a template virtual user in another tool which may have the behavioral characteristics you desire?